# IBM Notes - show open to-do's in calendar on due dates

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes, to-do

Is it possible to show open to-do's in IBM Notes (9.0.1) calendar on due dates? Currently I am seeing all open to-do's on current date (today).

Answer (score 0):

ToDos are displayed on the day they can be started.

If you want to have a ToDo show up only on the due-date, set the starting date to this date.

If the starting date is not set, or set in the past, the todo will move to the first day it could be completed, which will always be the present day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have not tried this, but it sounds to be a solution. But this is horrible. So any time I am going to update a record in To Do list, I will have to change both start date and end date.